# Как узнать архитектуру команд процессора в linux?

Tags: linux, процессор

Встал вопрос, какой пакет установить: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qemu-sgabios+noarch.rpm&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

в `/proc/cpuinfo` и `lscpu` показывается только архитектура самого процессора. Я не железнячник, прошу не закидывать камнями.

```
# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6320  @ 1.86GHz
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              3732.95
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1

# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6320  @ 1.86GHz
stepping        : 6
microcode       : 0xd0
cpu MHz         : 1867.000
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow
bogomips        : 3732.95
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6320  @ 1.86GHz
stepping        : 6
microcode       : 0xd0
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow
bogomips        : 3732.95
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: А что YasT в сусе уже убрали? Я не прикалываюсь, просто тыщу лет её не видел.

Comment: нет, не убрали,  но ведь должен же быть способ вытянуть это с консоли, хотя x86_64 походу и есть название архитектуры команд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Architecture:          x86_64

Чем это не устраивает? Архитектура CPU у Вас amd64, она же x86_64.

Comment: просто думал что архитектура команд и сама архитектура процессора не одно и то же

Comment: @Antoniok, вообще-то у автора был вопрос про то, какой пакет ставить, а не про архитектуру процессора и даже не про архитектуру, под которую собран linux (ведь в 32-битной системе, где большинство пакетов 32-битные, вполне можно поставить linux, собранный для 64-битной архитектуры).

Comment: В общем случае я не совсем прав, признаю. Внёс правку в ответ - "архитектура CPU".

Comment: @AntonioK мне нужно было разобраться как правильно определять архитектуру команд процессора, чтобы скачивать самому и ставить пакеты правильно.

Answer (score 8):

вообще-то в системе могут быть установлены пакеты разной архитектуры.

если пакетная система *rpm*-основная, то ориентироваться стоит на то, для какой архитектуры собрано большинство установленных пакетов. пример:

```
$ rpm -qa --qf "%{arch}\n" | sort | uniq -c
     91 i386
      2 i686
     68 noarch
      4 (none)
    464 x86_64
```

видно, что больше всего пакетов (464) — для архитектуры *x86_64*. она и есть основная.

---

для системы *deb*-основной чуть проще. есть основная архитектура. пример:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

и (могут быть) «сторонние» архитектуры. пример:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures 
i386
```

---

для дистрибутивов, основанных не на *rpm* и не на *deb*, подсказать сходу ничего не могу. надеюсь, в комментариях мой ответ дополнят специалисты по таким дистрибутивам.

---

есть, вероятно, универсальное решение: спросить у `glibc`, как основы операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

для 32-битной сборки `glibc` будет ответ `32`:

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

для 64-битной — `64`:

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```

Comment: Призываю знатоков слаки и генту :)

Comment: @OlegUP, дополнил универсальным ответом. надеюсь, подойдёт и для «слаки» и для всех остальных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

Answer (score 0):

Существует несколько вариантов названий этой технологии, которые иногда приводят к путанице.

x86-64 — первоначальный вариант. Именно под этим названием фирмой AMD была опубликована первая предварительная спецификация.

x64 — официальное название версий операционных систем Windows и Solaris, также используемое как название архитектуры фирмами Microsoft и Oracle.

AA-64 (AMD Architecture 64) — так архитектуру назвал популярный неофициальный справочник sandpile.org (внеся информацию практически сразу после публикаций первой предварительной спецификации) по аналогии с IA-64.
Hammer Architecture — название по первым ядрам процессоров, её поддерживавшим — AMD Clawhammer (гвоздодёр) и AMD Sledgehammer (кувалда).

AMD64 — после выпуска первых Clawhammer и Sledgehammer в названии архитектуры появилось название фирмы-разработчика AMD. Сейчас является официальным для реализации AMD.
Yamhill Technology — первое название реализации технологии компанией Intel. Иногда упоминалось название CT (Clackamas Technology).

EM64T — первое официальное название реализации Intel. Расшифровывалось как Extended Memory 64 Technology.
IA-32e — иногда встречалось совместно с EM64T, чаще для обозначения длинного режима, который в документации Intel называется «режимом IA-32e».

Intel 64 — текущее официальное название архитектуры Intel. Постепенно Intel отказывается от наименований IA-32, IA-32e и EM64T в пользу этого названия, которое теперь является единственным официальным для этой архитектуры со стороны компании Intel.